# NSJSONSerialization does not produce valid UTF8 string

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSDictionary that I try to convert to JSON using the following code

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:kNilOptions error:nil]; 
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The resulting `data` object looks good, but the final `NSString` remains NULL. If I create the `NSString` with `NSASCIIStringEncoding` I get a proper string object, but any multibyte UTF8 characters are of course maimed.

**Shouldn't `dataWithJSONObject` always yield valid UTF8 data whenever the function is succesful?**

Details: I'm pretty sure the culprit is somewhere in my input data (strings parsed from custom binary format), but there is quite a lot of data and I'm not sure how to efficiently detect where the problem is.

Comment: According to the doc, `The resulting data is encoded in UTF-8`. So that's strange.